# Why the memory consumption of python pandas dataFrame is so big?

Tags: python, pandas, large-files, multi-index

I am working with very large text files (about 4GB)

- the file has 3 columns where the first two are strings and the third is float.
- I first load this file using `pandas.read_csv()` - the first two columns will serve as keys in the index (tuple of 2 strings) and the float will be in a column.
- Given that I have a DataFrame (generated by `read_csv()`), I need to get values from the third column using a predefined list of keys.

When I try to accsses the data using `loc()` or `lookup()` the memory usage increases dramatically to ~16GB, which causes the thread to be very slow due to memory swapping.

Why does this happen? 
Are there other alternatives for my task?

This is a snapshot from my code:

```
similarity_df = pd.read_csv(similarity_dir, sep=' ', header=None, index_col=[0, 1])

values_df = similarity_df.loc[list_tup]
```

Comment: Without having your data the first thing here is that it's probably generating a temp df and then copying this to `values_df`, have you done any profiling?

Comment: Without having a sample of your data, we can't say much and this should be closed. But it sounds like it's making unwanted copies when you do indexing. Your (multi-?)index may be causing the trouble: *"first two columns will serve as keys in the index (tuple of 2 strings)"*. Well are they a MultiIndex or a tuple? Is `list_tup` a MultiIndex or a tuple? and what version of pandas? 0.16.1? Does this still happen on current version?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. It was because of MultiIndexes. Avoid using MultiIndexes with huge datasets if possible